# celery worker runs pops up an error "OS error too many open files"

Tags: celery, supervisord

> E1207 06:26:54.650322426    7649 wakeup_fd_pipe.c:52]        pipe
>   creation failed (24): Too many open files
>
> E1207 06:26:54.651353661   12228 completion_queue.c:850]
>   Completion queue next failed:
>   {"created":"@1512628014.649848140","description":"OS
>   Error","errno":24,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/wakeup_fd_pipe.c","file_line":53,"os_error":"Too
>   many open files","syscall":"pipe"}
>
> E1207 06:26:54.650492228    9620 wakeup_fd_pipe.c:52]        pipe
>   creation failed (24): Too many open files
>
> E1207 06:26:54.651371276    7649 ev_poll_posix.c:893]
>   pollset_work: {"created":"@1512628014.651362488","description":"OS
>
> Error","errno":24,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/wakeup_fd_pipe.c","file_line":53,"os_error":"Too
>   many open files","syscall":"pipe"}

**I am using**

```
celery version : celery==4.0.2
          django version : Django==1.10
          supervisor version: 3.2.0
          python version: python 3.6
          rabbitmq version : "RabbitMQ","3.6.10"
          redis version: Redis-server v=3.0.6
```

Tasks are run by the celery worker which at times fail due to some reason 
and the system fails to write  out any sought of log , only log i would get is the on i have shown above.

Once the task fails error like those pops up and my system goes into hang mode i would the restart the worker process so load gets reduced in my system

i runs the worker with supervisor

Comment: Did you found the cause of this?

Comment: most of the time this could be of memory issue of the system , you could upgrade you system to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

In celery each API hits open a new file and not closing them properly, Gradually it will exceed the ulimit.

As a solution for this problem you can put `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` in your celery configuration.

This will force your celery worker to restart after a certain number of tasks.

For example:
If you set `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 40`
When each worker complete 40 tasks it will restart. In effect this will close all open files which are opened by that particular worker.

Comment: It does seem like it's a "memory leak" type of issue, but is that the right way to fix it though? I wonder if there isn't a proper one.